# Is System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource equivalent to QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: winforms, qt, bindingsource, qsortfilterproxymodel

Coming from Qt, it seems to me that the BindingSource class provides the same functionality, and is intended to be used in the same way as the QSortFilterProxyModel in Qt.

After reading [When is it worth using a BindingSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042474/when-is-it-worth-using-a-bindingsource) and its answers:

> Filtering,Sorting while not changing the sort order of the records themselves (Filter/Sort)

And also:

> A BindingSource can act as a data source of another BindingSource

Those are the same features that a QSortFilterProxyModel provides in Qt.

Can someone who has experience in both Qt and Winforms tell me if my understanding is correct, and if not, what are the biggest differences between using a BindingSource and a QSortFilterProxyModel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with QSortFilterProxyModel, but `BindingSource` itself does not provide any sorting/filtering capabilities. It works as intermediator between actual data source and bound controls, delegating all feature requests to the underlying data source. IMO the main purpose of the `BindingSource` is to provide design time data binding support.

Comment: Hm, in one of the answers to the question I linked they say it provides "Filtering,Sorting while not changing the sort order of the records themselves (Filter/Sort)", so I assumed that was the case, but maybe they meant something else.

Comment: The answerers definitely have no idea what they are talking about :) See the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,3ae01e7a16f36ff8).

Comment: @IvanStoev can you maybe write an answer regerading the binding source (and maybe in comparison to my answer) and together those make up a decent answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev In particular, is a BindingSource more like a View than a Model, from an MVC point of view?

Comment: @Hayt: As I said, I'm not familiar with `QSortFilterProxyModel`, so I can't compare the two.

Comment: @sashoalm I think it's neither View nor Model (nor ViewModel from MVVM) - it's a Bridge or Adapter pattern. The Model is the actual underlying source and some standard interfaces/patterns used for data binding. Again, the main benefit of `BindingSource` for me is that you can set at design time `DataSource` property to `typeof(MyObject)`, and `DataGridView` columns can be populated and designed (reorder, hide, change properties), same for data bindings of text boxes etc. Then at runtime you assign the real data source, e.g. MyObject instance or List<MyObject> instance etc. and everything works

Comment: All this is sort of explained in the BindingSource [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) - **Remarks** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am no winforms expert but just by reading about it they are similar but different.*

So here my key concepts of the QSortFilterProxyModel. How much of this applies to the `BindingSource` or differs I cannot tell you much.

- The ProxyModels in Qt are an abstract model layered on top of your basic model (seems like with a BindingSource in common here). Though you cannot add controls etc. to this, because that is all they are: **Data Models**. You can attach this ProxyModel or also just a normal Model to the a View and this view takes care about what controls to display (the model can give "hints" though).
- The SortFilterProxyModel also can just Sort and Filter data based on Strings. You can derive from it for custom sorting/filter. No currency management etc.
- Qt also encourages this approach to write your own ProxyModels if you need them (you can also layer multiple ProxyModels on top of each other). *How much this differs from BindingSources and how much you can customize them I don't know*
- change notifications can be managed via the usual signals and slots concept in Qt, though the responsibility here lies in the Model beneath the ProxyModel and not in the ProxyModel.

**Conclusion:** It seems they have a similar concept and both (*accidently*) support sorting and filtering (*maybe because it's just such a common use-case*) but the basic concepts of the Model-View system they are put into seem just different.

*Again this is without any or very rough winforms knowledge, maybe someone else can answer that part and you have a good comparison then.*

Comment: When you stressed on the fact that QSortFilterProxyModel is just a model, did you mean that a BindingSource (or a DataSource) is more like a View, or maybe something in between?

Comment: This is where I lack knowledge about winforms. I read though that you bind controls to the BindingSource which for me seems to indicate "view" logics. Or a "binding" between a model and view. While a ProxyModel is still a model. Everything which takes a Model in Qt can also take a ProxyModel. How much this is true for BindingSources I don't know.